# J Unit Test Cases

Tags: java, junit

```
jdbcTemplate.query(searchQueryHelper.generateSearchQuery(searchRequest), resultSet -> {
        products.add(searchResultMapper.searchResultSetMapper(resultSet));
});
```

How to write J unit Test case for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends, what you want to test:

A unit test would only check that the calls are done with the correct parameters, so accidental changes are prevented. For this it is necessary that you do not instantiate any of your local variables that are used in the call with `new` but get them injected or passed into the tested method as parameter.

In a **unit test** you do not test, if the called method of other classes (or even 3rd party libraries) work correct - you just test the implementation *inside* the tested method.

To verify interactions with other classes, I would recommend to use a mocking library like [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) - although this is a bit controversial, because there is a rule "Do not mock types you don’t own", but it really depends on the exact scenario. (And do not mock the object under test - a common beginners mistake.)

You also can write an **integration test**, but that needs much more effort: you need to set up a database just for the test, including the necessary test data, then configure the code to use that test database, call the method, verify the results from the method (and if necessary also in the database) and then remove the database or set it into the pre-test state.

As you use JDBC here, it probably will be necessary that you use the same database engine as for production - with a higher level of abstraction like JPA or Hibernate you could use an alternative in-memory engine like [Apache Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/) or [H2](http://h2database.com) - those are usually faster in setup and teardown as no disk access is required.